# lm on element of a list

Tags: r, list, lm

Let say I have a list of three data frames

```
set.seed(55)
df1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(6), b=rnorm(6), c=rnorm(6))
df2 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(6), b=rnorm(6), c=rnorm(6))
df3 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(6), b=rnorm(6), c=rnorm(6))
l <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I now like to do a linear model with a and c of every data frame. I tried the following

```
for(i in l) {
  x <- (lm(l[[i]]$a~l[[i]]$c))
}
```

However I get the following error

```
Error in l[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

I'd like to have a list with every element an lm of a and c. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: The reason this fails is because when you do for(i in l){...} the first time through the loop i will be the first element of l.  It won't be the number 1 - it will literally be l[[1]]. So your code boiled down to `x <- (lm(l[[l[[1]]]]$a ~ l[[l[[1]]]]$c))` and then `x <- (lm(l[[l[[2]]]]$a ~ l[[l[[2]]]]$c))` and so on.  Since the elements of l are data frames (which are also lists) R is telling you that you can't subscript a list using a list (data.frame).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `lapply`, like this:

```
lapply(l, lm, formula = a ~ c)
```

Comment: So simple and clean. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with the format you proposed (the for loop) you need to use something like `1:length(l)` in your for loop statement.

Also, if you keep assigning things to x you will keep overwriting it. In what I have below I am assigning the linear model to the 24th, 25th, and 26th letters of the alphabet, so you have a lm called x, y, and z. Other suggested solutions are much cleaner.

```
for(i in 1:length(l)) {
 assign(letters[24:26][i], (lm(l[[i]]$a~l[[i]]$c)))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is to be preferred but it might be useful for people coming from a for-loop mentality to be told that the `lapply` solution ( at least the one where it's result is assigned to 'x') is equivalent to this:

```
x<-list();
for(i in seq_along(l) ) {
      x[[i]] <- lm(a~c, data=l[[i]])
    }
```